# Dos tablas es más eficiente que solo una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Espero hacerme entender, 
Estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación en `php`, donde tengo que almacenar las **facturas** en tablas. 
Estoy almacenando en tablas diferentes según el año ej: **facturas19**.

Mi cuestión es si es mas eficiente almacenar todas las facturas en una sola tabla (ya crea aprox 3000 por año) o esta bien como estoy haciendo.

**facturas.sql**

```
ID,NO,CLIENT,DATE,DETAILS

2,3004,02749.., 15/03/2019, (detail object)

... X 4000
```

Otro problema que tengo es cuando deseo consultar una factura del año pasado tengo poner facturas**18**, facturas**17**, etc .

Comment: espera.. creas una tabla para cada año?

Comment: Si, esta correcto?  Esque almaceno como 3000 facturas cada año, y mi pregunta no se colapsa todo eso en una sola tabla

Comment: ¿por qué colapsar? si al momento de mostrar la información no le vas a enseñar 3000 facturas de *golpe* a un usuario pues solo va a consultar algunas, además si creas una tabla por cada año, entonces hasta que año dejarías de hacer tablas?

Comment: La cuestión es este caso es buscar los datos que son relevantes para la base de datos, por ejemplo campos relevantes como los que tienes arriba `ID,NO,CLIENT,DATE,DETAILS`, la tabla puede aguantar muchos datos, y 3000 no son tantos como crees. Re-formula la base de datos y piensa como afecta en tu aplicación.

Comment: Esto esta mal a tantos niveles... en fin.. miralo de otra manera.. como haces para consultar todas las facturas de determinado cliente? Cuando se piensa en bases de datos, se piensa en millones de registros para arriba. Si tenes dudas sobre como debe funcionar una base de datos, te recomendaria leer sobre teoria de bases de datos.

Comment: Creo que ha quedado claro que hacer una tabla por cada año es lo peor que puedes hacer, rompe la normalización y dificulta cualquier consulta, revisa las formas normales e intenta llevar tus tablas minimo a 3NF ( https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forma_normal_(base_de_datos) ). Igualmete 3k registros al año son 300k en 100 años, cualquier base de datos puede con eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, es más eficiente almacenar todas las facturas en una sola tabla.

- Por un lado el código de la aplicación que vaya a manejar la tabla será más eficiente (siempre trabajarás contra una misma tabla sin que el nombre de la misma tenga que ser un parámetro).
- Por otro lado, los limites de tablas son muy elevados ([aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html) puedes consultar información en inglés al respecto). Resumiendolo mucho, el límite es el límite de tamaño máximo de archivo que permita tu SO. Eso son millones de facturas!

Otras consideraciones a tener en cuenta son:

- Al grabar todas las facturas en una tabla, necesitarás una forma de referirte de manera única a una factura en concreto, así que si el número de factura se reinicia cada vez (es decir, si por ejemplo la primera factura de cada año siempre va a ser la 1) tendrás que tenerlo en cuenta a la hora de actualizar y/o eliminar registros, para ello puedes crear un campo indice que sea distinto del numero de factura (y que nunca se repita) o incorporar la fecha al indice de la tabla. Esto te lo recomiendo incluso aunque ahora pienses que no se reiniciará en indice cada año.
- En tu diseño, parece que guardes los detalles en un campo binario o de tipo objeto... lo normal en un diseño de este tipo seria utilizar una tabla diferente que contenga esos detalles (por ejemplo las líneas de factura) de tal manera que ambas tablas estan referenciadas entre si por lo que se conoce como una clave foranea. Es decir, cada linea de la tabla de lineas de factura, tiene información de a que factura pertence...

Muchos de los conceptos anteriores son muy básicos, te puede ser útil antes de continuar con tu desarrollo familiarizarte algo más con el diseño de bases de datos en general, puedes consultar:

- https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/fundamento-de-las-bases-de-datos-modelo-entidad-relacion
- [Este documento](http://www.nachocabanes.com/tutors/ibd006.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Muchas gracias. También tengo otra duda es mejor guardar los datos (facturas)  en una base de datos no estructurada (archivos) Json, xml (este ya esta obsoleto)  o da igual la eficiencia de la app si la base de datos es estructurada o no,ten en cuenta de que uso un host gratuito (luego me mudare a un privado), y guardo los detalles así: **$cantidad:$identicador:$precio** creo q me ahorro de estar usando otra tabla

Answer (score 2):

Añádele el campo fecha a la tabla facturas, y guardas todo en una sola tabla.

Para añadir el campo: `alter table facturas add fecha date`

A la hora de buscar, si quisieras ver las facturas del año 2017:

```
select * from facturas where DATEPART(yy, YourDateColumn) = 1996
```